# how to write this code as link click animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

how to write this code as link click animation. This animation work when i load my page.

```
 (function () {
        var index = 0;
        var boxes = $('.box1, .box2, .box3, .box4, .box5, .box6');

        function start() {
            boxes.eq(index).addClass('animated');
            ++index;
            setTimeout(start, 80);
        };
        start();
    })();
```

i need to write this animation, when i click a link.i wrote  this code for animate a CSS animation.

Comment: Add Click event on link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a id="btn" href="#">Click Me</a>

$('#btn').click(doWork);

function doWork() {
        var index = 0;
        var boxes = $('.box1, .box2, .box3, .box4, .box5, .box6');

        function start() {
            boxes.eq(index).addClass('animated');
            ++index;
            setTimeout(start, 80);
        };
        start();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like..

```
jQuery("a#linkOne").click(function () {
    var index = 0;
    var boxes = $('.box1, .box2, .box3, .box4, .box5, .box6');

    function start() {
        boxes.eq(index).addClass('animated');
        ++index;
        setTimeout(start, 80);
    };
    start();
}
```

`HTML`

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="linkOne" > CLick Me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boxes.each(
    function(event){
        this.style. //do whatever you want with your style via traditional DOM here
                    //It'll influence all the elements saved in boxes
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
(function () {
  var index = 0;
  var boxes = $('.box1, .box2, .box3, .box4, .box5, .box6');

  boxes.on('click', function() {       
    boxes.removeClass('animated');
    $(this).addClass('animated');
  });
})();
```

Needs testing but should work!